# Why does my Mac's graphics freeze when I put a video game in full screen?

Tags: macos, mac, graphics-card

When I play The Walking Dead (Telltale, season 1) via Steam on my Mac, it only works if it's not full screen. When I switch to full screen, the screen freezes. The screen doesn't get stuck, it just goes all weird, as seen in my linked screenshot.

I have a Macbook Retina, mid 2012. Graphics card NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which Walking Dead game are you trying to play? I was going to look up the hardware requirements, but I saw that there are 4 games.

Comment: @DrZoo Telltale, season 1